# Is a Riemann integral of a real-valued function a number or a function?

Tags: calculus, definition

For example, if we define $F(x)=\int^x_a f(t)dt$, where $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $F(x)$ is a function. Or for a 2 variables real-valued integrable function $f(x, y)$, $G(x)=\int^b_a f(x,y)dy$, then $G(x)$ is a function. But for $\int_a^b f$, is it just a number rather than a function?

Comment: $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$ is a function, and $\int_a^b f(t) dt = F(b)$ is a number.

Comment: I disagree with @JairTaylor's comment.  $F(x) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ is still "just" a number.  Specifically, it is the value of $F$ when evaluated at $x$.  The function $F$ is defined in terms of Riemann integrals, but none of the integrals themselves are functions.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I was using $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ to refer the function $F$ itself.   It's pretty common usage to write $f(x)$ to mean a function $f$. (e.g. if someone asks you for the derivative of $f(x) = 3x+4$ you presumably don't say that it is $0$ because $f(x)$ is a constant given by evaluating $f$ at $x$...) 

But yes, for any given $x$, $F(x)$ is a number.

Comment: Admittedly my comment above was confusing since I implicitly assumed $b$ was a constant while $x$ was a dummy variable defining a function.  It should read "The function $F$ defined by $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is a function, while $\int_a^b f(t)dt = F(b)$ is a constant for any fixed $b$."

Comment: @JairTaylor I think that it is a common mistake of beginners to say that $f(x)$ is a function. $f(x)$ is the value of the function $f$, when evaluated at $x$. If someone asks me to find the derivative of $f(x) = 3x+4$, I will know what they mean, but they are being imprecise. What they should actually ask is "What is the derivative of $f$, where $f(x) = 3x+4$?" (or, I suppose, "What is the derivative of $x \mapsto 3x+4$?").  This confusion between a function and the value of a function seems to cause students a lot of problems, hence I think that it is worth being very careful from the start.

Comment: @JairTaylor Your second comment is a much better presentation, i.e. "$F$ is defined by $F(x) = \dots$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Riemann integral is a number.

If $f : [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a Riemann integrable function then, by definition, the *Riemann integral* of $f$ is given by
$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{\delta\to 0} \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(x_n^*) (x_{n}-x_{n-1}),
$$
where $a = x_0 < x_1 < \dotsb < x_N = b$ is any partition of $[a,b]$ with $x_n - x_{n-1} < \delta$ for all $n$, and $x_n^* \in [x_{n-1}, x_n]$.

For any partition of $[a,b]$, the sum on the right will be a will be a real number (since $f(x_n^*)$ and $x_n-x_{n-1}$ are real for every $n$).  Thus the term on the right is the limit of a sequence of real numbers.  The limit of a sequence of real numbers is, again, a real number, hence the Riemann integral is a real number.  Since the variable is not really important here, the above notation will often be abbreviated to
$$ \int_{a}^{b} f, $$
but this notation indicates the same number discussed above.

That being said, there is something else going on, which might explain your confusion.  Roughly speaking, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that if there is a function $F$ with derivative $f$, then
$$ F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t, $$
where $a$ is an arbitrarily chosen constant in the domain of $F$, and $x$ is *any* element in the domain of $F$.  Note that, even here, the Riemann integral is a real number:  first, we fix some some point $x$ in the domain of $F$, and then we determine the value of $F$ at that point (that is, we determine $F(x)$) by evaluating a Riemann integral.  This process can be used to *define* a function—it gives us a way of evaluating $F$ at every point in its domain—but the integral itself is not a function.

Finally, there is one other notational wrinkle:  if the derivative of $F$ is $f$, then we say that $F$ is an *antiderivative* of $f$.<sup>[1]</sup>  The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus could be restated as "If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then
$$ F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x, $$
where $a$ and $x$ are as above."  Because of this link between derivatives, antiderivatives, and (Riemann) integrals, it is common to write
$$
F = \int f
$$
in order to indicate that $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.  In this notation, the "integrals" have no limits, and $\int f$ doesn't really refer to an integral at all (though it is often called the "indefinite integral").  In this case, it would be fair to say that $\int f$ is a function,<sup>[2]</sup> but $\int f$ no longer denotes a Riemann integral.

---

[1]  Note the use of the indefinite article:  $F$ is **an** antiderivative, not **the** antiderivative.  This is important, because if $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all appropriate $x$, then
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \bigl(F'(x) + C\bigr) = f(x) $$
for any constant $C$.  Hence antiderivatives are not unique; both $x \mapsto F(x)$ and $x\mapsto F(x) + C$ are antiderivatives of $f$.

[2] It may also be worth noting that it is a little bit of a lie to say that
$$ \int f $$
is a function—in reality, it is probably better to think of it as an *equivalence class* of functions, which are equivalent up to addition of a constant.  But this distinction is typically irrelevant in elementary courses, and is easily dealt with in more advanced settings.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just wondering, for the function $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ to be well-defined, does $f$ only need to be integrable rather than to be derivative of $F$?

Comment: Roughly speaking, if $f$ is an integrable function, then there exists a function $F$ defined by $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$  The FTC then tells us that $F' = f$.  So $F$ needn't *a priori* be assumed to be an antiderivative of $f$,  but it turns out that it is.

Comment: Does $f$ need to be continuous, so that $F' = f$, or $f$ only need to be integrable then FTC hold?

Comment: @Cathy I am being intentionally imprecise regarding the statement of the fundamental theorem, because the details don't *really* matter.  The important idea is that if $f$ is integrable on some interval $[a,b]$, then the function $F$ defined by $$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ is well-defined.  In the case of Riemann integration, if $f$ is continuous, then $F$ is differentiable and $F' = f$.  However, [other generalizations exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you consider the parameters $a$ and $b$, if they are fixed numbers, then $\int_a^bf$ is a number, but if you consider them as variables, you have a function of two variables

$$F(a,b)=\int\limits_a^bf(t)dt,$$

where $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is just the particular case obtained by fixing the value of $a$ and changing the notation of the variable $b$ by $x$.

So, it is mostly a matter of perspective.

Comment: In your notation, $F$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or some subset thereof), but $F(a,b)$ is still a number.  $F$ is a function, $F(a,b)$ is the **value** of that function at the point $(a,b)$.  I think that one of the biggest stumbling blocks that students have when learning this material is that they don't have a good sense of the difference between a function and the evaluation of a function at a point.  I feel like your answer does little to alleviate this confusion.

Comment: @XanderHenderson $F(a,b)$ is the analytic representation of the function $F$, not a number. From that notation, we are able to know the space of the domain and the relation defined by $F$. It shouldn't be confused with $F(2,3)$, $F(a,b)$ only specifies what are the variables of the function. I could have defined $F(a,b,f)$, resulting in a function of 3 variables now. The problem is when to interpret that an expression is a function when some of its components turn out to be variables. In that spirit, we should be able to understand that even $F(x,y)=\int_a^bf(t)dt$ is a valid representation.